# Why Vaadin Window.ResizeListener is not invoked

Tags: java, vaadin7

I have the following class as following:-¨

```
public class ExchangeWindow extends Window implements Button.ClickListener, Window.ResizeListener  {

public ExchangeWindow() {
    center();
    setWidth(600, Unit.PIXELS);
    setHeight(430, Unit.PIXELS);
    setModal(true);
    setResizable(true);
    setImmediate(true);
    addListener(this);
 }

@Override
public void windowResized(ResizeEvent resizeEvent) {
    if(left.isVisible()) {
        //left.setWidth(600, UNITS_PIXELS);
        exchangeTable.setWidth(600, UNITS_PIXELS);
    }
}
```

I found this link: https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/117302 . I guess my code is similar to this. windowResized method is never called whether I set setImmediate(true); or setImmediate(false);

I am using Vaadin 7.

What is wrong? How to catch the resize event notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code sample in that link and the date of the post (8 years ago), the link you provided is probably for a Vaadin6 problem, as [Vaadin7 was released in 2013](https://vaadin.com/blog/the-next-reindeer-is-here-vaadin-7-0-0-is-out).

Anyway, instead of `addListener(this);` you should use `addResizeListener(this);`:

```java
public class WindowWithResizeListener extends Window implements Button.ClickListener, Window.ResizeListener {

    public WindowWithResizeListener() {
        center();
        setWidth(600, Unit.PIXELS);
        setHeight(430, Unit.PIXELS);
        setModal(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setImmediate(true);
        addResizeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void windowResized(ResizeEvent resizeEvent) {
        Notification.show("Resized!");

    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(Button.ClickEvent clickEvent) {

    }
}
```

And there's the output with Vaadin 7.7.9:

[image: Window with resize listener]

Comment: But I get the event only if I try to resize the window by dragging the mouse. It doesn't fire this event when I click maximize/restore button. How can I catch maximize/restore button click?

Comment: @masiboo ah, you did not mention this in your question. Nonetheless, there's a different event triggered for that action, and another listener you can use, eg: `addWindowModeChangeListener(event -> Notification.show("New window mode:" + event.getWindowMode()))` which will tell you if the window is either `Maximized` or `Normal`